# how to create series for each group from 1 to till group ends

Tags: excel

I have a data in excel like below

```
month
1        
4
12
12
12
12
6
8
7
12
12
12
12
12
12
7
10
12
12
12
```

How to give series for only 12's like below

```
month   Series
1   
4   
12        1
12        2
12        3
12        4
6   
8   
7   
12        1
12        2
12        3
12        4
12        5
12        6
7   
10  
12        1
12        2
12        3
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: starting with B2: `=if(A3=A2,B1+1,"")` and copy down

Comment: @DirkReichel that'll give problems because of the zero-length strings. It also doesn't work for the last set of 12s. If you went for `=IF(OR(A3=A2,A2=12),B1+1)` then you'd get round both problems albeit having *FALSE* as your non-12 value.

Comment: I should have used my brain more than just one second :P

Comment: @TimEdwards If only 12's count... then `=IF(A2=12,N(B1)+1,"")` for B2 and copy down should do ^^;

Comment: That's a good trick with N(), I'd not used that before.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try the following code in the worksheet code module where you put your data. I assume that column A is **Month** and column B is **Series**.

```
Sub Checking_Value()
Dim i As Long, LastRow As Long, n As Long

LastRow = Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
n = 0

For i = 1 To LastRow
    If Cells(i, 1).Value = 12 Then
        n = n + 1
        Cells(i, 2) = n
    Else
        n = 0
    End If
Next i

End Sub
```